# How to make Maven to download source code and javadoc for specific dependencies?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I need for specific dependencies documentation, for some documentation and source code. What is the best way to tell maven to do that?

Comment: You can configure in your settings to download source/javadoc or in the IDE you can configure that.

Comment: Why did you accept an Answer that uses a command-line solution when your Question was about the IntelliJ IDE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, IntelliJ should automatically download sources for you although sometimes you may need to click on 'Download Source'. This actually uses Maven to fetch the source and javadoc.

If you want to do it with the Maven command line an example of a command that downloads javadoc for a specific artifact is:

```
mvn dependency:sources -Dclassifier=javadoc -DincludeArtifactIds=<my-artifact>
```

If you need both the source and javadoc just remove the javadoc classifier.

Comment: Where exactly would one find this 'Download Source' item to click?

Comment: @BasilBourque I didn't include full details of the 'Download Source' as IntelliJ isn't actually mentioned anywhere in the question. It is tagged so I made a passing reference to it. I'm conscious that searches for IntelliJ may be leading here however so I'm prepared to update the answer if it would be helpful.

Comment: The Question is tagged with "IntelliJ".

Answer (score -1):

For javadoc include this tag in the dependency

```
<classifier>javadoc</classifier>
```

Comment: **Incorrect.** If you add `<classifier>javadoc</classifier>`, you get *only* the JavaDoc, not the classes jar and not the sources jar. If you add `<classifier>sources</classifier>`, you get *only* the source code, but no classes and no JavaDoc.

Comment: The Question asked for documentation *and* source code. I tried the `<classifier>` in a POM file in IntelliJ 2017. If I specify the classifier for JavaDoc per your Answer, I get *only* the JavaDoc, no source. So this Answer does not resolve the Question. Please correct me if I am wrong or confused.

Comment: The question asked about javadoc and source-code. I only answered for the javadoc, which according to you is working fine.